NextJS get session from client component
when user logs in; session is created with user data, i want to access that session when calling this function:
app/utils/getSession.js
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export async function getSession() {
  const session = (await cookies()).get("session")?.value;
  if (!session) return null;
  return await decrypt(session);
}


if i call this function from client component it will return error You're importing a component that needs "next/headers". That only works in a Server Component but one of its parents is marked with "use client", so it's a Client Component.
so i guess calling getSession function from client component will turn getSession.js into a client component ? if so then how can i access the session from client component ?
Header.js
"use client"
import { getSession } from "@/app/utils/getSession";

const Header = ()=>{

    const user = getSession(); // return promise but can't use async await in a client component

return (
<header>
     ...
     session.user ? <a>Login</a> : <a>Logout</a>
</header>
)

}

